# How to create a snipmate snippet with ultisnips?

Tags: plugin-ultisnips

I'm trying to create a "snipMate" snippet which I've copied an example from https://github.com/honza/vim-snippets/blob/master/snippets/haskell.snippets

For example adding:

```
snippet main
    main :: IO ()
    main = ${0:undefined}
```

To the file/buffer opened via `:UltiSnipsEdit` (`~/.vim/UltiSnips/haskell.snippets`).

However the above errors with:

```
UltiSnips Error:

Missing 'endsnippet' for 'main' in ~/.vim/UltiSnips/haskell.snippets:3
```

I assume it's a different syntax for ultisnip / snipmate. However where do I place/configure the snipmate snippets?

I couldn't find sufficient info in `:help UltiSnips` searching for `snipMate`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They should instead go to `~/.vim/snippets/` so in the above example `~/.vim/snippets/haskell.snippets`.